# Trying to retrieve Message Text from Azure Queue using web api but message text is encoded. how do i remove encoding

Tags: azure-queues

when i retrieve  something the output is encoded.

QueueClient queue = new QueueClient(connectionString, "outqueue");
string value = await RetrieveNextMessageAsync(queue);

```
        return value;
```

RetrieveNextMessageAsync:

```
if (await theQueue.ExistsAsync())
        {
            QueueProperties properties = await theQueue.GetPropertiesAsync();

            if (properties.ApproximateMessagesCount > 0)
            {
                QueueMessage[] retrievedMessage = await theQueue.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1);
                string theMessage = retrievedMessage[0].MessageText;
                await theQueue.DeleteMessageAsync(retrievedMessage[0].MessageId, retrievedMessage[0].PopReceipt);
                return theMessage;
            }
```

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTcvV.png)

Comment: Could you please tell me how you define method `RetrieveNextMessageAsync`?

Comment: Would need more information about RetrieveNextMessageAsync. How does it look?

Comment: As far as I knew, in default, if we use V12 SDK to manage Azure queue, the mesage is just UTF-8 string. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10242#issuecomment-735949498. Could you please check the message encoding vai Microsoft Storage explore?

Comment: @Dhatri Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your message encoding is base64, you can use the following code to retrieve it with package `Azure.Storage.Queues`

```
[HttpGet("getMessage")]
        public async Task<string> GetMessageAsync() {
            string connectionString = "";
            var options = new QueueClientOptions {
                MessageEncoding= QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
            };
            var queue = new QueueClient(connectionString, "myqueue", options);
           
            var message = await RetrieveNextMessageAsync(queue);
            return message;
        }
        static async Task<string> RetrieveNextMessageAsync(QueueClient theQueue)
        {
            if (await theQueue.ExistsAsync())
            {
                QueueProperties properties = await theQueue.GetPropertiesAsync();

                if (properties.ApproximateMessagesCount > 0)
                {
                    QueueMessage[] retrievedMessage = await theQueue.ReceiveMessagesAsync(1);
                    string theMessage = retrievedMessage[0].MessageText;
                    await theQueue.DeleteMessageAsync(retrievedMessage[0].MessageId, retrievedMessage[0].PopReceipt);
                    return theMessage;
                }

                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Regarding how to check message encoding, you can use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows)
[image]